# How can I translate rooms details on multilanguage site on solidres

Tags: joomla, translation

Hello I would like to ask how can I translate the Room Details of Solidres plugin on multi language site. I saw the falang plugin but is there an other way? I am using Gavick hotel template on Joomla .I want on the Gavick news pro (module that takes data from Solidres and display it )  when the guest of the site choose a language ,to display the Solidres rooms on that language, if he choose an other to display it in other language.

Answer (score 0):

If the plugin follows the Joomla standard it can be translated using [Neno Translate](http://www.neno-translate.com). It is free and open source.

Note: I work for Neno Translate, but the answer is correct and I have highlighted the affiliation so I am allowed to share this answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response I will try it and let you know.

Comment: Let us know if you have any issues.